# GNSDK on ubuntu fails to run (using java wrapper)

Tags: gracenote

I finished implementing an application on windows7 OS using the gnsdk java wrapper - all went fine there.

Now I want to install my application on ubuntu (compiling it on that platform as well), and I came to an error : "GnException   Failed to load GNSDK module" - of course I changed the library i am using to the linux-64 directory (so file in there).

My app didn't run.....

I tried to compile the sample app - musicid_stream - and got to the same issue. I use the following execute command:

java -Djava.library.path=../lib/linux_x86-64 -classpath ./gnsdk.jar:./musicid_stream MusicIDStream   licence ../lib/linux_x86-64
(all file references are ok)

RESULT:
"GnException    Failed to load GNSDK module"

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What build of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Are you using a Makefile?